# How to transfer the whole balance of ERC20 token?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, tokens, gas, gas-price

At the moment I have this code:

```
//............
const contract = new ethers.Contract(smartContractAddress, ERC20_ABI, provider);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(prKey, provider);
const txSigner = contract.connect(signer);
let tx = txSigner.transfer(ADMIN_WALLET, 0.001);
return tx;
//............
```

Now I want to change the code so that it always transfers the whole balance of a ERC20 token.
I'll then be checking the balance this way:

```
const myBalance = await contract.balanceOf(walletAddress);
```

Do I understand correctly that I'll be able to send **precisely** the amount equal to `myBalance`? And I won't have to worry about subtracting the gas price off it? Nor to estimate it at all either?

Because the gas price, however it may be, gets paid off the ETH balance.

---

And in this case the gas calculation, estimate and subtraction will be automatic?

If so, could I make manual in an attempt to reduce it? I'd be willing to wait longer for a TX to get mined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can transfer the exact myBalance amount of your ERC20 tokens.

```
const myBalance = await contract.balanceOf(walletAddress);
let tx = txSigner.transfer(ADMIN_WALLET, myBalance);
```

The gas fee will be automatically deducted from your ETH balance, not the tokens being transferred. You don't need to worry about estimating or subtracting gas fees.
In case you want to set the gasPrice manually:

```
let tx = txSigner.transfer(ADMIN_WALLET, myBalance, {
 gasPrice: PricePerGas (preferably in Gwei format)
});
```